# Is it possible to only have one Feature Attribute Window open in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gui

I suppose it's by design that when you click through(identify) your features, for every feature it opens the attribute window (which is good, i have enabled the checkbox to automatically open the window).

My question is whether it's possible to limit those, so that the program only shows 1 feature attribute window? Sort of an "auto-close" checkbox?